# How to change class for all elements retrieved by document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which contains 3 rows. Each row has the class: `.myClass`.

I then query for the table rows with `document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')` and iterate over the elements, changing each row's class to `.otherClass`.

However,

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('otherClass'))
```

only returned one row.

And, when I looked at the DOM, only the first `.myClass` row had its class changed to `.otherClass`; the other remained untouched.

How can I change the class of all `.myClass` rows to `.otherClass`?

```js
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0];
var x = c.getElementsByClassName('myClass');

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].className = 'otherClass';
}

x = c.getElementsByClassName('otherClass');

console.log(x);  // only one element
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr class="myClass2">
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="myClass">
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="myClass">
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I cannot see otherClass in your html.

Comment: `var x = c.getElementsByClassName('otherClass');` don't redeclare `x`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, he's setting it as part of the code

Comment: @BhojendraNepal `x[i].className='otherClass';`

Comment: @royhowie, it's incorrect, but it will not cause any problems

Comment: Point of this piece code is make function for button that will show more rows of certain tables on website. So if you click LOAD MORE button it will replace class that got DISPLAY: none; to one thats visible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName`, like other HTML collections, is "live", that is, when you assign another class name to its member, it's removed from the collection on the fly and its length gets decremented. That's why your loop runs only once.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
alert("before: " + x.length);
x[0].className='otherClass';  
alert("after: " + x.length);
```

```css
.myClass { color: black }
.otherClass { color: red }
```

```html
<b class="myClass">hi</b>
<b class="myClass">hi</b>
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection):

> An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.

---

To answer in context to your question, you could set the className of the first element until there are none left in the collection:

```
while(x.length > 0) {
   x[0].className = 'otherClass';  
}
```

Comment: This is news to me - I never knew the arrays were "live".  I assumed (as I guess most people would) that an array created by `.getElementsByClassName` would not be changed by a change to the objects contained with them

Comment: @freefaller it's not exactly an array; it's an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: Yeah i didnt know that also. SO how you work around this if you wanna modify className of items that you got by getElementsByClassName?

Comment: @Mitre iterate only while the collection has a length

Comment: Nice that solution with WHILE works. Thank you for yoru answer.

Comment: I new this was the issue but couldn't realize that a while loop solves it. duh. I was thinking about passing values, then pulling back with reference ... sometimes you just gotta keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

As [georg pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31311967/2476755), [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns  a ["live"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) collection. That means the array will "update" as the elements change.

To fix your problem, you should use a while loop, iterating while `x.length` exists, and only changing the first element of the `HTMLCollection`.

```js
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0];
var x = c.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
while (x && x.length) {
  x[0].className = 'otherClass'
}
var y = c.getElementsByClassName('otherClass'); 
alert(y.length);
```

```css
.myClass {
  display:block;
  background-color: red;
}
.otherClass {
  display:block;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
<tr class="myClass2">
 <td>Content</td>
 <td>Content</td>
</tr>
<tr class="myClass">
 <td>Content</td>
 <td>Content</td>
</tr>
<tr class="myClass">
 <td>Content</td>
 <td>Content</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Georg is right. Elements array is updated on the fly, so you cannot depend on it's length;

Try this code:

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0],
    x = c.getElementsByClassName('myClass');

while (x.length) {
    x[0].className = 'otherClass';
}
var y = c.getElementsByClassName('otherClass');
alert(y.length);
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvazo557/)